# DQN unstable predictions

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn

i implemented DQN from scratch in java, everything is custom made. I made it to play snake and results are really good. But i have a problem.

To make network as stable as possible, im using `replay memory` and also `target network`. The network is converging really well. But after some time it just breaks.

This is a graph (X - played games, Y - average points scored )

[image]

This 'break' happens usually few games after i update `target` network with `policy` network.

Settings i use for DQN:

```
 discount factor: 0.9
 learning rate: 0.001
 steps to update target network: 300 000 (means every 300k steps i update target network with policy)
 replay memory size: 300 000
 replay memory batch size: 256 (every step i take 256 samples from replay memory and train network)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks for answers.

Comment: How does the loss behave?

Comment: Hey, im not really sure what you mean by that

Comment: every time you run the train function you get a report on the loss function. does it decrease/increase/remain stable?

Answer (score 0):

Look up "catastrophic forgetting"

Try adjusting your replay-memory size and the number of steps to update your target network.